# Error con webpack en proy. react informa: error Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\User_'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, webpack, symfony4

Estoy haciendo una integraciòn backend symfony con frontend de react. Segui una guia [tutorial](https://blog.pedrojanula.xyz/integrando-react-con-symfony/) y la documentaciòn oficial de symfony.

Intente correr el comando `yarn run encore dev --watch` para generar el transpilado correspondiente. **fallo** con el siguiente error que copio:

```
Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\User_' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\web_cotizacion_repuestos'
```

El archivo de configuración *webpack.config.js* tiene la siguiente forma:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

 Encore
// Directorio donde se almacenarán los assets ya compilados.
.setOutputPath('public/build/')

.setPublicPath('/build')

// Nuestro archivo app.js, que será compilado y almacenado en /web/build/app.js
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
// .addEntry('buscarRepuesto', './assets/js/Components/buscar repuesto/buscarRepuesto.js')

// Habilitar el mapeo de recursos en Desarrollo.
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

// Borra el contenido del directorio /web/build antes de volver a compilar una nueva versión.
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

// Muestra una notificación cuando se ha finalizado la compilación.
.enableBuildNotifications()

// Activa React
.enableReactPreset()

// .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
//     // add additional presets
//     babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-flow');

//     // no plugins are added by default, but you can add some
//     babelConfig.plugins.push('styled-jsx/babel');
// }, {
//     // node_modules is not processed through Babel by default
//     // but you can whitelist specific modules to process
//     includeNodeModules: ['foundation-sites'],

//     // or completely control the exclude rule (note that you
//     // can't use both "includeNodeModules" and "exclude" at
//     // the same time)
//     exclude: /bower_components/
// })

.copyFiles({
        
        from: './assets/img',
    
        // optional target path, relative to the output dir
        to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
    
        // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
        //to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    
        // only copy files matching this pattern
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
    })
     ;

  // Exporta la configuración final
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Si alguien me puede orientar sobre como resolver esta incidencia. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontre la soluciòn modificando mi archivo **webpack.config.js** para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
 // Directorio donde se almacenarán los assets ya compilados.
.setOutputPath('public/build/')

.setPublicPath('/build')

// Nuestro archivo app.js, que será compilado y almacenado en /web/build/app.js
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

// Habilitar el mapeo de recursos en Desarrollo.
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

// Borra el contenido del directorio /web/build antes de volver a compilar una nueva versión.
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

// Muestra una notificación cuando se ha finalizado la compilación.
.enableBuildNotifications()

// Activa React
.enableReactPreset()
;

// Exporta la configuración final
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Previamente limpie la cache y actualice los paquetes de node,npm,yarn.
Les dejo un enlace a [tutorial sobre integracion de REACT con SYMFONY](https://blog.pedrojanula.xyz/integrando-react-con-symfony/) esta bien explicado y es simple.